# How to redirect users to unique callback url after authentication?

Tags: django, auth0, auth0-lock

I'm using Lock and Django to authenthicate my users, whenever it's done I'd like to redirect them to the same page they were, problem is that my urls have unique UUID and I can't list all of them under *Allowed Callback URLs*, I originaly had two ways to do so:

1. Specifying callback urls in Lock `redirectUrl` parameter - **Problem** : Callback URL mismatch. (can't specify each new unique url to *Allowed Callback URLs*)
2. Specifying my unique urls to Lock and POST it then receive it back from auth0 along with the user informations, so I can use it to redirect the user. - **Problem:** I don't think such feature exist. (**EDIT:** it does, see answer.)

Are there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Is there a problem with auth0 redirecting to a single URL? Your app can redirect the user a second time, if necessary. Alternatively, you can use `popup` mode instead of `redirect`, that way users never leave the page to begin with.

Comment: @sytech The solution you're suggesting is the second one I listed, each generated url comes with a unique uuid in the url, to be able to redirect someone I have to receive it from auth0 and I'm not sure I can send custom POST, and receive it back using Lock. For UX/UI reasons I cannot use popup mode, it'll slightly affect our client conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research solution number 2 is possible, Auth0 allow us to send custom encoded data through the `state` parameter that can be retrieved from the callback.

> For the most basic cases the `state` parameter should be a nonce as
>   shown in the example below. But this field can also be a Base64
>   encoded json object that can hold multiple values **such as a return URL**.

More informations can be found on this link: https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/oauth2/oauth-state